# R works, but gives me random results

Tags: r, ggplot2

For scientific analysis, I am following this tutorial:
https://uw-madison-microbiome-hub.github.io/Microbiome_analysis_in-_R/

Specifically, I would like to use this script to make permanova:

```
library(vegan)
library(qiime2R)
library(phyloseq)
library(ggplot2)

# import data

ASVs <- read_qza("/path/table.qza")

metadata <- read.table("/path/metadata16S.tsv", , sep='\t', header=T, row.names=1, comment="")
metadata <- metadata[-1,] 

tree <- read_qza("/path/rooted-tree.qza")

taxonomy <- read_qza("/path/taxonomy.qza")
tax_table <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(taxonomy$data$Taxon), ";"))
colnames(tax_table) <- c("Kingdom","Phylum","Class","Order","Family","Genus","Species")
rownames(tax_table) <- taxonomy$data$Feature.ID

# phyloseq object
physeq <- phyloseq(
  otu_table(ASVs$data, taxa_are_rows = T),
  phy_tree(tree$data),
  tax_table(tax_table),
  sample_data(metadata)
)

# convert ot relative abundance
physeq_rel <- microbiome::transform(physeq, "compositional")
physeq.ord.wuni <- ordinate(physeq_rel, "PCoA", "unifrac", weighted=T)
b.div.wuni <- plot_ordination(physeq_rel, physeq.ord.wuni, type= "samples", color= "MyParameter") + geom_point(size=3)
b.div.wuni <- b.div.wuni + stat_ellipse() + ggtitle("Weighted Unifrac")  + theme_classic()
print(b.div.wuni)
```

The problem is that after running this script, I get purely random data every time I run it, but only on my Linux, while if I run it on other computers with a window OS, the results are correct!

What could be causing the problem?

The only clue I have is that during the installation of ggplot2 I had problems regarding libmkl_rt.so.1, already present in conda, but which R could not find. I solved the problem by renaming the files as suggested in https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/275#issuecomment-947940126

I have no idea what to do ...

Thank you for your help

Andrea

Comment: By *"I get purely random data every time I run it"* do you mean that you get different random results every time, or the same random result?

Comment: Can you do these step by step and see where the results start to diverge?

Comment: It's not obvious (unless I missed it) which step might be causing any randomness.  However, if you want to "fix" a random event from giving different (random) results, I would suggest setting a randomization seed in your code before you begin:  (i.e. `set.seed(12345)`).

Comment: I go with `chemdork123`. `sample_data()` function from `phyloseq` package may need `set.seed`!

Comment: GregorThomas I get similar, but different results in the plotted graph that I obtain...in the next step, the permanova results are completely illogical....so, there's something wrong somewhere in R, that doesn't work properly....

iod the first steps # "import data" are only to import data, in #phyloseq object the results seems the same...so it remains # relative aboundances

chemdork123 it shouldn't be a randomness step....I've tried the seed but results remain the same....

....there's someting wrong somewhere...

Comment: I obtain similar PCA graph, where each sample is in a "correct position"...however every time that I run the script, the position changes a bit. Also, x and y axes vary, for esample one time x=21.9% y=10.5%, another time x=24.5% y=19.7%....similar results, near a correct value, but wrong!

Comment: This reeks of being caused by some sort of numerical instability. After doing some research into what libmkl_rt.so.1, I think it might be some sort of math kernel library i.e., a library created to do specific calculations repeatedly and efficiently, which supports this hypothesis at least somewhat. If this is true, then there is probably no easy way to resolve this problem, since you would need to figure out where the instability is and fix it

Comment: Question: Are you dealing with very small numbers and/or very large numbers? If so, then that could be a cause of the problem. If you can rework the analysis so that the numbers you are supplying it are more moderate, then it could solve the issue. However, looking at the problem you are trying to solve, I don't know if there is any way to get out of this issue

Comment: if it works on windows, it must also work on linux! :)

I tried to reinstall all libraries ... it didn't work ... any ideas? can i do some tests to figure out what's wrong?

Can I try to uninstall and reinstall something?

Comment: This "numerical instability" quite possibly could be floating point error and a difference between how the math libraries on the different versions handle floating point arithmetic.  To get an understanding of what I mean, `.1 == .3/3` evaluates to false in RStudio.  There's loads of other examples, but basically there will always be some rounding in floating point arithmetic.  If the way in which floating point numbers are rounded is not the same across platforms, then these can give different results in calculations - especially when a lot of numbers are involved.

Comment: another hint the first error message was:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘igraph’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/home/User/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-igraph/00new/igraph/libs/igraph.so':
libmkl_rt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

as reported above, I solved the problem by renaming the "libmkl_rt.so.1" files found in conda, after which the installation was successful.

Could this be the cause? a bad installation of this component ?!